# Detection of inverted color mode in a browser

Tags: browser, colors, webgl, detection

do you think there is a way to detect inverted color mode in the browser? There is one thread [How to detect MAC OS' inverted color mode in javascript / css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104388/how-to-detect-mac-os-inverted-color-mode-in-javascript-css), which is saying it's not possible via CSS or JavaScript.

I have been thinking about rendering pixel in WebGL and then reading it's color value. Not sure how exactly inverted color mode works though.

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: WebGL's colors are independent of any browser settings so WebGL will not help you here

Comment: Well inverted color mode is not browser setting, but system setting.

Comment: Whatever, WebGL doesn't pay any attention to system settings either